# Use of the Adjective "Invariant" in Mathematical Literature

Tags: terminology, smooth-manifolds, convention

I'm currently reading Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, in which he makes a remark along the following lines: "The next corollary can be viewed as a more invariant version of the rank theorem." My question isn't about the corollary or the rank theorem itself, but about Lee's use of the word "invariant." This word is thrown around a lot in the community, and I have always seen it used as a noun, meaning a property left unchanged by a transformation. But here it's an adjective, and I'm having trouble figuring out what Lee is trying to communicate. What does it mean for a *statement* to be invariant? Does it relate to the noun meaning I'm familiar with?

For reference, here's the theorem and the corollary:

> **Rank Theorem:** Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds of dimensions $m$ and $n$, respectively, and $F : M \to N$ is a smooth map with constant rank $r$. For each $p \in M$ there exist smooth charts $(U,\phi)$ for $M$ centered at $p$ and $(V,\phi)$ for $N$ centered at $F(p)$ such that $F(U) \subset V$, in which $F$ has a coordinate representation of the form $\hat{F}(x^1,\ldots,x^r,x^{r+1},\ldots,x^m) = (x^1,\ldots,x^r,0,\ldots,0)$.
>
> **Corollary:** Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds, let $F : M \to N$ be a smooth map, and suppose $M$ is connected. Then the following are equivalent: (a) For each $p \in M$ there exist smooth charts containing $p$ and $F(p)$ in which the coordinate representation of $F$ is linear. (b) $F$ has constant rank.

Comment: Your question would make more sense if you quoted the corollary in full. I could say some vague words, but they might end up being inconsistent with the corollary that caught your eye, which dissuades me from saying anything.

Comment: @LeeMosher Good point, just added the theorem and the corollary my original question.

Comment: I would have expected a “more invariant version” to be in language not using coordinates: for instance, talking about linear maps rather than matrices. But I wouldn’t say that this statement would so qualify. But the whole matter is not my field…

Comment: I am not sure what the author is trying to say. Maybe less dependent on a choice of local coordinates? I would just let it go. Whatever he is trying to say is tangential.

Comment: @BenW "Invariant", as a noun, is commonly used in algebraic topology (among other things).  It means a quantity, measurement, object, or thingy which remains unchanged under homemorphism (or homotopy, or whatever kind of morphism is of interest).  For example, the genus of a surface is a homeomorphism invariant:  if two surfaces are homeomorphic, then they have the same genus.

Comment: Looks like he's just using "invariant" to mean "coordinate-free," though I guess it could be argued that he's talking a statement that, for example, is unchanged on replacing $F$ by $\beta F \alpha$ for diffeomorphisms $\alpha:M \to M$ and $\beta:N \to N$.